# Retrieve attribute using generics

Tags: c#, generics, attributes

Given the repeating code in my project in the form:

```
public static ReasonAttributes GetAttributes(this Reason value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name == null) return null;
    var field = type.GetField(name);
    if (field == null) return null;
    return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(ReasonAttributes)) as ReasonAttributes;
}
```

Is it possible to create a generic so I can avoid repeating code?  Along the lines of:

```
public static T GetAttribute<T, T1>(T1 value)
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name == null) return default(T);
    var field = type.GetField(name);
    if (field == null) return default(T);
    return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(T)) as T;
}
```

I get the error on the return line:

```
The type parameter <T> cannot be used with the `as` operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a `class` constraint.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy, just put on a type constraint that says `T` must inherit from `Attribute`.

```
public static T GetAttribute<T>(object value)
    where T : Attribute
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name == null) return default(T);
    var field = type.GetField(name);
    if (field == null) return default(T);

    return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(T)) as T;
}
```

You don't need `T1` at all; you can call `GetType()` on anything (except `null` of course). You never even used `T1` in the body of the method, so clearly it doesn't matter what type the parameter is.

`where T : class` would work as well, but you may as well enlist the compiler to forestall somebody thoughtlessly calling `GetAttribute<String>()`.

Comment: Much better answer than mine. Good job Sir :-)

Answer (score 3):

Shouldn't you add `where T : class` to your method definition so your code knows T can is a class and can be instantiated ?

```
public static T GetAttribute<T, T1>(T1 value) where T : class
{
    var type = value.GetType();
    var name = Enum.GetName(type, value);
    if (name == null) return default(T);
    var field = type.GetField(name);
    if (field == null) return default(T);
    return Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(T)) as T;
}
```